# Boolean field (attribute type) in PostGIS with OGR Python

Tags: python, postgis, gdal, ogr

In my project I'm using ogr (python bindings) for inserting spatial data in PostGIS.

The spatial data comes in all different formats (CSV, Shapefile, GeoJSON) etc and before creating new tables in PstGIS I'm reading the properties (or attributes) of the features and do some processing.

I've ran into an issue when I want to create a boolean field in the PostGis table. I could not find a boolean type in the OGR variable list that can be used for creating a field definition as I do with string and integer types:

```
    # For string type
        ogr.FieldDefn(field_name, ogr.OFTString)

    # For integer type
        ogr.FieldDefn(field_name, ogr.OFTInteger)
```

Does anyone know how to create the [Postgresql boolean type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/datatype-boolean.html) with OGR Python?
Have I missed something in the [OGR Python docs](http://gdal.org/python/) ?

Comment: Boolean seems to be subtype of integer type http://www.gdal.org/ogr__core_8h.html#a24d96814a798fa79bffd2b8ce6135284.

Comment: Ok so i realised that the subtype is not available for python bindings of gdal < 2. So for using this I have to upgrade. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!